# Replacing the first occurrence of a symbol in a line

Tags: notepad++

i would want to replace only the first occurence of a specific character /sybmol in a line to be replaced with a particular symbol.

can anybody suggest how could this be achieved

ex :  i want to replace first occurence of & with and

input : me **&** she is playing & she came up with a bat & ball & ballon
Output : me **and** she

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REGEX in Notepad++ find/replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171292/regex-in-notepad-find-replace)

Comment: Do you want to remove everything after "she"?

Comment: nope i  just want to replace only the first occurence of a particular word or symbol in a line

Answer (score 1):

Do a regular expression find/replace like this:

- Open Replace Dialog
- **Find What:** `^([^&]*)&`
- **Replace With:** `\1and`
- Check **regular expression**
- Click Replace or Replace All

**Explanation:**

- `[^&]*` matches everything that is *not* a `&` and the first `^` anchors the match at the line start
- the last part `&` matches the `&` and because the first part cannot contain a `&`, it is the first `&` in a matched line
- the parentheses mark the first part for reuse in the replacement as `\1`
- so `\1` becomes `me` in your example and the `&` is replaced by `and`