# Notepad ++ wildcards on dialogue

Tags: replace, notepad++

how to find and replace all characters with empty after Adam: name using a wild card in notepd++?

For example, I have the following 4 rows:

```
Eva: hi how are you
Adam: I'm fine thank you, and you?
Eva: well, I am cooking dinner, I am fine
Adam: excellent what are you cooking?
```

I want to have the following 4 rows to isolate Eva dialogue lines:

```
Eva: hi how are you

Eva: well, I am cooking dinner, I am fine
```

thank you, Sid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REGEX in Notepad++ find/replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171292/regex-in-notepad-find-replace)

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^Adam:.+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    Adam:   # literally
    .+      # 1 or more any character but newline
$           # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]